# Using multiple templates and bindings in a single view

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using KnockoutJS to display a list of images. Say I am using a template X to show this list, and I have defined another template Y to display details in a separate dialog of a selected image. I am facing issues binding the selected image with this detail template Y. Below is a mock/partial code of my actual view

ViewModel:

```
var viewModel {
    photos:ko.observableArray(//list of photos),
    showDetails:function(item){
        //show the details of the selected image in dialog
    }
 };
```

The binding is applied as

```
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This is how X is defined

```html
<script id="X" type="text/html">
  {{each(i,item) photos()}}
      <a href="javascript:;" data-bind="click:function(){showDetails(item);}">show Image</a>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

This is how the template is applied

```html
 <div class="list" data-bind="template: {name:'X'}"></div>
```

This is a mockup of template Y

```html
 <script id="Y" type="text/html">
   <img src="{url}" />
 </script>
```

How should I define the showDetails function to apply the bindings to template Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample that works: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/MCQgY/.

Easiest way is to define an observable that represents the selected photo. The click binding then just needs to set the observable by calling it like: viewModel.selectedPhoto($data).

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have additional questions/problems with it.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying the same thing but instead of setting the value as viewModel.selectedPhoto($data) i was trying viewModel.selectedPhoto=$data